# Get all the rows which have mismatch between values in columns in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have the following pyspark dataframe `df1` :-

| SL No | category 1 | category 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apples | Oranges |
| 2 | Apples | APPLE FRUIT |
| 3 | Grapes | Grape |
| 4 | Bananas | Oranges |
| 5 | Orange | Grape |

I want to get the rows of the pyspark dataframe where the column values are not matching b/w columns `category 1` and `category 2` handling for case partial string match(category 1 contains only Apples/Bananas/Orange/Grapes strings and likewise Category 2 only contains only those distinct strings under Category 2) :-

| SL No | category 1 | category 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apples | Oranges |
| 4 | Bananas | Oranges |
| 5 | Orange | Grape |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please avoid column names with spaces.

My df

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([(1,   'Apples',   'Oranges'),
(2, 'Apples',   'APPLE FRUIT'),
(3, 'Grapes',   'Grape'),
(4, 'Bananas',  'Oranges'),
(5, 'Orange',   'Grape')],
('SL No',   'category1 ',   'category 2'))

df.show()



   new =(
    #Make string columns have a common case and put them into a comma separated array
     df.select('*',*[split(initcap(F.col(c)),'\s').alias(c+f'{"_1"}') for c in df.drop('SL No').columns])
    #Filter the non wanted using a higher order functio
     .filter(expr("filter(category1_1, (x,i)->rlike(x,category2_1[i]))")[0].isNull())
    #Drop columns not wanted
     .drop('category1_1','category2_1')
     ).show()

+-----+---------+---------+
|SL No|category1|category2|
+-----+---------+---------+
|    1|   Apples|  Oranges|
|    4|  Bananas|  Oranges|
|    5|   Orange|    Grape|
+-----+---------+---------+
```

Comment: I tried this , getting the following error :- `extraneous input '_1' expecting {')', ','}(line 1, pos 25)`

Comment: Also what does this `.filter(expr("filter(category1_1, (x,i)->rlike(x,category2_1[i]))")[0].isNull())` do

Comment: I have added my df which is a replica of what you gave except I eliminated spaces in column names. My solution works and I cant reproduce your error. Further, you have accepted the answer.. so little confused

Comment: Thank you, I had round brackets like `(T)`  in my column name ,which is why I got the error, it resolved when I used tilde..